# Migrate my normal RecyclerView to RecyclerView Databinding

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have issue when I change some value, example delete comment in my recyclerview it's doesn't update automatically, Google says use LiveData DataBinding RecyclerView, is anyone ever to make RecyclerView LiveData databinding please help me out

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class TabDetailHotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//GLOBAL
public static MainActivity mainActivity_;

TextView TVGameDate;
TextView TVGameTitle;
ImageView IMGGameImage;

TextView TVSeenCounter;
TextView TVCommentCounter;
TextView TVLikeCounter;

ImageView IMGSeenView;
ImageView IMGCommentView;
ImageView IMGLikeView;

ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;


//EVENT BUS
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredMessageTrending event) {
    getMessageTrendingMainActivity(event.SendMessageUrutan, event.SendTotalThread, event.SendMessageIDComment, event.SendMessageComment, event.SendMessageEntryTime, event.SendMessageisEdited, event.SendMessageEditTime);

}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredMessageTrendingLogin event) {
    getMessageTrendingLoginMainActivity(event.SendMessageUrutan, event.SendTotalThread, event.SendMessageIDComment, event.SendMessageComment, event.SendMessageEntryTime, event.SendMessageisEdited, event.SendMessageEditTime, event.SendMessageEditable);

}
public void getMessageTrendingMainActivity(int ReceivedMessageUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, String ReceivedMessageIDComment, String ReceivedMessageComment, String ReceivedMessageEntryTime, int ReceivedMessageEdited, String ReceivedMessageEditTime){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Load Comment Not Login :( >> ReceivedMessageComment:"+ReceivedMessageComment+", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void getMessageTrendingLoginMainActivity(int ReceivedMessageUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, String ReceivedMessageIDComment, String ReceivedMessageComment, String ReceivedMessageEntryTime, int ReceivedMessageEdited, String ReceivedMessageEditTime, int ReceivedMessageEditable){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Load Comment Login :) >> ReceivedMessageComment:" + ReceivedMessageComment, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    createDummyDataComment(ReceivedMessageUrutan, ReceivedTotalThread, ReceivedMessageIDComment, ReceivedMessageComment, ReceivedMessageEntryTime, ReceivedMessageEdited, ReceivedMessageEditTime, ReceivedMessageEditable);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitydetail_tabhot);



    ToolbarX = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(ToolbarX);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mDummyIDContent = intent.getStringExtra("DummyIDContentPKG");
    mDummyTitle = intent.getStringExtra("DummyTitlePKG");
    mDummyPublishTime = intent.getStringExtra("DummyPublishTimePKG");
    mDummyImageOriPKG = intent.getStringExtra("DummyImageOriPKG");
    mDummyShortDescription = intent.getStringExtra("DummyShortDescriptionPKG");
    mDummySeen = intent.getIntExtra("DummySeenPKG", 0);
    mDummyComment = intent.getIntExtra("DummyCommentPKG", 0);
    mDummyLike = intent.getIntExtra("DummyLikePKG", 0);
    mDummyisComment = intent.getIntExtra("DummyisCommentPKG", 0);
    mDummyisLike = intent.getIntExtra("DummyisLikePKG", 0);
    mDummyisBookmark = intent.getIntExtra("DummyisBookmarkPKG", 0);





    date_Behaviour = findViewById(R.id.date_behavior);

    IMGGameImage = findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

    TVGameDate = findViewById(R.id.date);
    TVGameTitle = findViewById(R.id.title);

    TVSeenCounter = findViewById(R.id.TV_SeenCounter);
    TVCommentCounter = findViewById(R.id.TV_CommentCounter);
    TVLikeCounter = findViewById(R.id.TV_LikeCounter);


    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.error(UtilsNews.getRandomDrawbleColor());



    TVGameDate.setText(mDummyPublishTime);
    TVGameTitle.setText(mDummyTitle);

    TVSeenCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mDummySeen));
    TVCommentCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mDummyComment));
    TVLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mDummyLike));


    Glide.with(this)
            .load(mDummyImageOriPKG)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(IMGGameImage);
    /*     initWebView(mUrl);*/


    ImageButton BTNSendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews = findViewById(R.id.BTN_SendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews);

    final TextView ETSendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews = findViewById(R.id.ET_SendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews);
    BTNSendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String TheMessage = ETSendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews.getText().toString();
            if(!TheMessage.equals("")){
                if(mainActivity_!=null) {
                    mainActivity_.rncryptorLoadSendEditDelete("SendComment", mDummyIDContent, TheMessage);
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(TabDetailHotActivity.this, "You don't send anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ETSendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews.setText("");
        }
    });

    //
    if(mainActivity_!=null) {
        mainActivity_.rncryptorLoadSendEditDelete("LoadComment", mDummyIDContent, "");
    }

}

private void initWebView(String url) {
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

ArrayList<ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment> modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments = new ArrayList<ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment>();
AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener listenerDetailHotTrendingNewsComment;
public void createDummyDataComment(int ReceivedMessageUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, final String ReceivedMessageIDComment, String ReceivedMessageComment, String ReceivedMessageEntryTime, int ReceivedMessageEdited, String ReceivedMessageEditTime, int ReceivedMessageEditable) {
    modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments.add(new ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment(ReceivedMessageIDComment,ReceivedMessageComment,ReceivedMessageEntryTime,ReceivedMessageEditable,ReceivedMessageEditTime));

    if(ReceivedMessageUrutan ==  ReceivedTotalThread-1){
        listenerDetailHotTrendingNewsComment = new AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRowDetailHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(View view, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRowMessageEditClick(View view, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRowMessageDeleteClick(View view, final int position) {
                String[] YOURCHOICE = {"Yes", "No"};
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabDetailHotActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Do you want to delete this comment?");
                        builder.setItems(YOURCHOICE, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if(which == 0){
                                    Toast.makeText(TabDetailHotActivity.this, "Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    if(mainActivity_!=null) {
                                        mainActivity_.rncryptorLoadSendEditDelete("DeleteComment", modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments.get(position).getIdcontent(), "");
                                    }
                                }else if(which == 1){
                                    Toast.makeText(TabDetailHotActivity.this, "You don't delete the Comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
            }


        };

        RecyclerView RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment = findViewById(R.id.RVDetail_HotTrendingNewsComment);
        RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.setHasFixedSize(true);
        AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment adapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment = new AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment(this, modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments, listenerDetailHotTrendingNewsComment);
        RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.setAdapter(adapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment);
        //Optimized
        RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RVDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    supportFinishAfterTransition();
}


//EVENTBUS
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

This is my activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
    tools:context=".TabDetailHotActivity">
 
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        android:text="Title of News"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="a time ago" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/IMG_SeenView"
                            android:src="@drawable/watch"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TV_SeenCounter"
                            android:paddingTop="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TV_SeenCounter"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IMG_CommentView"
                            android:text="999"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:textSize="14dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/IMG_CommentView"
                            android:src="@drawable/comment_off"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TV_CommentCounter"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TV_CommentCounter"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IMG_LikeView"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="999"
                            android:textSize="14dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/IMG_LikeView"
                            android:src="@drawable/heart_off"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TV_LikeCounter"
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TV_LikeCounter"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:text="999"
                            android:textSize="14dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_intrinsic_padding"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Second.Light" />




                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/darkgrey">

                    <ProgressBar
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <WebView
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                        android:id="@+id/webView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>





                </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RL_Bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ET_SendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Type a comment..."
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/BTN_SendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/BTN_SendMessageDetailHotTrendingNews"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/RVDetail_HotTrendingNewsComment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_behavior"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:behavior_autoHide="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/round_white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="410dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_date"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="01 January 1990"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>





</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is AdapterComment.java

```
public class AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment> modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments;

private AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment> modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments, AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments = modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemdetail_hottrendingnewscomment, null);
    return new DetailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v, mListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final DetailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder detailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (DetailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    final ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment modelDetailHotTrendingNewsCommentX = modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext).load(modelDetailHotTrendingNewsCommentX.getMessageimage()).into(detailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGMessageImage);
    detailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVMessageUsername.setText(modelDetailHotTrendingNewsCommentX.getMessageusername());
    detailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVMessageDescription.setText(modelDetailHotTrendingNewsCommentX.getMessagedescription());
    detailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVMessageDate.setText(modelDetailHotTrendingNewsCommentX.getMessagedate());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelDetailHotTrendingNewsComments.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class DetailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


    ImageView IMGMessageImage;
    TextView TVMessageUsername;
    TextView TVMessageDescription;
    TextView TVMessageDate;

    private RelativeLayout ROWDetailHotTrendingNewsContainer;
    TextView TVMessageEdit;
    ImageView IMGMessageDelete;


    private AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

    public DetailHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView, AdapterDetailHotTrendingNewsComment.RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        IMGMessageImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_MessageImage);
        TVMessageUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_MessageUsername);
        TVMessageDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_MessageDescription);
        TVMessageDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_MessageDate);

        ROWDetailHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_DetailHotTrendingNewsContainer);
        TVMessageEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_MessageEdit);
        IMGMessageDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_MessageDelete);

        mListener = listener;
        ROWDetailHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
        TVMessageEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGMessageDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ROW_DetailHotTrendingNewsContainer:
                mListener.onRowDetailHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(ROWDetailHotTrendingNewsContainer, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.TV_MessageEdit:
                mListener.onRowMessageEditClick(TVMessageEdit, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_MessageDelete:
                mListener.onRowMessageDeleteClick(IMGMessageDelete, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onRowDetailHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowMessageEditClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowMessageDeleteClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

This is ModelComment.java

```
public class ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment {
private String idcontent;
private String messageimage;
private String messageusername;
private String messagedescription;
private String messagedate;
private int messageisedit;
private String messageedittime;

private String messageedit;
private String messagedelete;


public ModelDetailHotTrendingNewsComment(String idcontent, String messagedescription, String messagedate, int messageisedit, String messageedittime) {
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
    this.messagedescription = messagedescription;
    this.messagedate = messagedate;
    this.messageisedit = messageisedit;
    this.messageedittime = messageedittime;
}

public String getIdcontent() {
    return idcontent;
}

public void setIdcontent(String idcontent) {
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
}

public String getMessageimage() {
    return messageimage;
}

public void setMessageimage(String messageimage) {
    this.messageimage = messageimage;
}

public String getMessageusername() {
    return messageusername;
}

public void setMessageusername(String messageusername) {
    this.messageusername = messageusername;
}

public String getMessagedescription() {
    return messagedescription;
}

public void setMessagedescription(String messagedescription) {
    this.messagedescription = messagedescription;
}

public String getMessagedate() {
    return messagedate;
}

public void setMessagedate(String messagedate) {
    this.messagedate = messagedate;
}



public String getMessageedittime() {
    return messageedittime;
}

public void setMessageedittime(String messageedittime) {
    this.messageedittime = messageedittime;
}

public String getMessageedit() {
    return messageedit;
}

public void setMessageedit(String messageedit) {
    this.messageedit = messageedit;
}

public String getMessagedelete() {
    return messagedelete;
}

public void setMessagedelete(String messagedelete) {
    this.messagedelete = messagedelete;
}
```

}

[image: The data doesn't update automatically when I set another value]

Comment: A few things: clean up your code. Remove all the code, that isn't relevant for this question, which means: keep the `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation, the model and show us where you're updating your data.
I couldn't find anything in your code relating to `LiveData´ so I'm a bit unsure what you mean by using `LiveData` to update the list. There's no Databinding as well, so why are you referring to using Databinding?

Comment: Yeah this time in my code I am not use LiveData databinding, I thought the only way to update the recyclerview automatically when some value was changed is to use Recyclerview LiveData Databinding, that why I need to ask someone that has ever do that and I can implement it to my RecyclerView so I can update my RecyclerView automatically

Comment: Ok, well that's not what you asked about and while it might be possible to update `LiveData` directly inside the `Adapter` it's never recommended not using any of the `notify**` methods on the adapter instead. So you might have your data inside a `LiveData`, but you should always call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged` or `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged` or some other `notify**` method.
What are you trying to accomplish with automatically updating the data of the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Darwind I upload the photo of problem I had, you can check it out, when I change some value of any item in my RecyclerView it doesn't updated automatically unless I reopen the Activity

Comment: Your picture doesn't really help I'm afraid.